# How to get FMV ( Fair Market Value ) of a stock on 31 Jan 2018

Tags: income-tax, india, stock-markets

I want to know how to get FMV of a stock ( Ex. `SBIN` ) which is purchased from `NSE`.

I want to know this for filling ITR ( India ).

I tried over `nse` website as well as `moneycontrol` website but could not find the FMV of the stock.

I visited https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm and used filter to get high and low stock values of 31 Jan 2018. But I could not find any FMV info.

Comment: What did you find? Did you get price information for other days? Did you find no mention of the stock at all?

Comment: I got the price information of today as well as of 31 Jan 2018 but could not get FMV. I visited 
 https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm

Comment: You will get the list from below link: http://www.harshitaraj.com/2018/02/equity-price-on-31st-jan-2018-for.html Thanks n Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fair Market Value of the stock is the price information you found. Unless there were no transactions that day, the price information shows what buyers/sellers were willing to pay for the stock on that day.

For your situation unless you need the price information for a specific moment during the day in question, just use the closing price for that date.

Comment: Yes for listed stocks it's the closing price to be used